# Mail crashes on attempts to display message contents in Mavericks

Tags: mail.app, macos

When I click or double click on any message in the messages list on any account in Mail in Mavericks (10.9), Mail crashes immediately with the error

```
Application Specific Information: 
   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: 
   '*** -redComponent not valid for the NSColor NSCalibratedWhiteColorSpace 0 1; need to first convert colorspace.'
abort() called
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

What can I do to prevent this crash? I can't read any of my mail!

Comment: System gives back: 2013-10-23 17:57:44.610 defaults[781:507] Domain (com.apple.mail) not found.
Defaults have not been changed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open `Terminal.app` (under `/Applications/Utilities`) and run

```
defaults delete com.apple.mail ColorQuoterColorList
```

Comment: So mail.app will crash under Mavericks if you changed the default colors for "Fonts & Colors" > "Color quoted text" in a previous version of Mac OS X?

Comment: @Blaise: I'm not sure that's all it takes, but I don't recall doing anything else so — apparently yes.